# Combining two fields in a selectlist with one field being a related record

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a Title table and a Member table, the relationship works fine between them both. I want to be able to join the text of the two fields in another controller.

**Member model class**

```
public string LastName { get; set; }
public Title Title { get; set; }
public string FullName => string.Format("{0} {1}", Title.TitleName, LastName);
```

**Title model class**

```
public int ID { get; set; }
public string TitleName { get; set; }
public ICollection<Member> Member { get; set; }
```

**Selectlist section in controller**

```
ViewData["MemberID"] = new SelectList(_context.Members, "ID", "FullName");
```

When this is running all I'm getting is a null object for Title instead of getting the related title name of the record.

What am I getting wrong in this understanding?

Comment: Have you tried `_context.Members.Include(member => member.Title)`?

Answer (score 0):

By default, EF won't populate the related properties unless you explicitly tell it or set it to automatically populate them. You have basically three choices:

**Eager loading**

As already commented by @Progressive,

```
ViewData["MemberID"] = new SelectList(
    _context.Members.Include(member => member.Title),
    "ID",
    "FullName");
```

should work.

**Explicit loading**

This method will work fine if you need to populate navigational properties for a single object, but not so much for a collection, as it uses `DbContext.Entry(...)` API.

**Using Lazy-loading proxies**

This method will enable lazy loading of all navigation properties that are overridable. The only things you need to do is to install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies` package and enable it with a call to `UseLazyLoadingProxies()` method when building your `DbContext`. After doing that, all navigation properties should be loaded automatically.

More information can be found in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data).